# jQuery target next `ul` element from `li` with class `active`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Cannot figure what I am doing wrong, as I get no errors. Essentially I want to target the very next `ul` element from the one and only `li` containing a class of `active`.

My HTML is:

```
<li id="abc"></li>
<li id="account" class="active">
  <a href="#"><img class="menu-logo-symbol" src=" /img/app/logo-symbol.png">Your Account</a>
  <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked sub-nav nav-list" style="display: none;">
    <li id="account-details"></li>
    ......
  </ul>
</li>
```

I have tried the following:

```
var checkElement = $('li.active').next('ul');
checkElement.slideDown('normal');
```

and

```
$('li.active').next('ul').show();
```

and also

```
$('li.active').next('ul').slideDown('normal');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, `next()` and `prev()` find siblings, or elements at the same depth in the DOM. In this case, since the `ul` is a child element of `.active`, you'd actually need to use the `find()` method like so: `$('li.active').find('ul').first().show();`

Using `first()` in combination with `find()` ensures that it'll only return that single `ul` element and not any others that may be nested deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Done as follows:

```
$('.active ul:first').slideDown('normal');
```

I still do not understand why this did not work

```
$('li.active').next('ul').show();
```